# Optional arguments - argument passed is not an integer

Tags: coldfusion

I'm sure this must be a simple one, but no amount of tweaking seems to work (I'm hoping I haven't misunderstood the fundamentals here!).

I have defined a function in a CFC as follows:

```
public void function createWidget(  
        required any event
      , required String widgetType
      , String elementId=""
      , integer refreshRate="0"
      , required integer rowNumber
      , required integer colNumber
      , required integer width
      , required integer height
      , String title=""
      , String bgColour="orange" ){
```

As you can see, there are some required arguments, and some that are not required that I have provided a default value for (e.g. `integer refreshRate="0"` ).

Now I am calling this function using named arguments, trying to take advantage of the optional arguments, e.g:

```
createWidget( event:event
               , widgetType:'blank'
               , rowNumber:1
               , colNumber:1
               , width:2
               , height:1  
               , title:'Empty Widget' )
```

So I have not provided any value for `refreshRate` in this case, but I get the error:

```
The REFRESHRATE argument passed to the createWidget function is not of type integer.
```

I have also tried updating the default value for `refreshRate` to remove the quotation marks (`integer refreshRate=0`)  but still the exact same problem.

Can anyone spot what I am doing wrong?

---

**UPDATE**
I have also tried actually passing in the variable refreshRate (adding `refreshRate:0` to the function call) and I still get the same error!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, apparently switching the arguments to type "`numeric`" fixes this - not sure why Integer isn't accepted? It's a legit CF type right?

Comment: Nope, only numeric is supported.

Comment: To elaborate, there about fourteen [built in argument types](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7e47.html). All other values are treated as the "name" of a component. What the error really means is that CF thinks `Integer` is the name of a component and rejects the parameter because it is not an instance of `Integer.cfc`.